# Error: Cannot find module 'index'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm attempting to deploy a lambda implemented in typescript via CDK.

I am able to deploy the lambda successfully, but when I test it, I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'index'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'index'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:996:17)",
    "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1031:21)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1194:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1200:1"
  ]
}
```

The lambda is declared in CDK like so:

```
    const postImages = new lambda.Function(scope, utils.prefixed('post_images'), {
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
        handler: 'index.lambdaHandler',
        code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('./sd_service/post_images')
    })
```

The contents of `./sd_service/post_images` looks like this:

[image]

### index.ts:

```
import { Context, APIGatewayEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';

export const lambdaHandler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    console.log(`Event: ${JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)}`);
    console.log(`Context: ${JSON.stringify(context, null, 2)}`);
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: 'hello world',
        }),
    };
};
```

### tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
    "display": "Node 18",

    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es2022"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2022",

        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

### package.json:

```
{
  "name": "post_images",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.111",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.6",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1330.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-lambda": "^1.0.7"
  }
}
```

What have I done wrong, and how can I get the lambda to work?

Comment: Depends on how you deploy to lambda. Can you please add the steps on how you deployed the project to lambda?

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you have index.ts at the root of your project after deploying. A common problem when deploying an archive: if you archive a folder with all the files, then in the root of the archive will be a folder with files, but there should be files (including the entry point).

Comment: How can we zip in that way

Comment: You can select the files inside the folder and then add to archive. This solved the issue for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Ok,so you have keep in mind that the **zip should be like
Folder>files.**
Rather *files* should be in root.

To do so,first go to that folder through terminal.
For example my folder name is hello.

```
Cd hello
zip -r abc.zip ./
```

This will solve you root file issue.
And then you upload it to lambda through S3 bucket (if file size is more than 50mb)

Answer (score 3):

Volodymyr`s answer is correct, you have to have the file js that contains your handler in the root of the zip folder.

Here is how it looks like inside one of my Lambda functions` zip folder, for example:
[image: zip folder containing three files, including index.mjs, and one folder (node modules)]

References:

1. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started.html) you can check a quick Getting started guide from AWS.
2. And [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html#:%7E:text=zip%20files.-,Creating%20a%20.zip%20deployment%20package%20with%20dependencies,-If%20your%20function) you can check how to create a .zip deployment package with dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your CDK configuration, you might need to run **npm build** to generate the JavaScript files from TypeScript before deploying using **cdk deploy**. The missing index.mjs file should then be present. This solved the issue on a project that was generating the same error message.

Alternatively, you could consider using **NodejsFunction** to define your Lambda function. This removes the need for separate dependencies in the lambda directory and handles TypeScript. All Lambda Function dependencies can be installed in the root directory in a single package.json and those required for the Lambda to run will be automatically bundled and deployed using es-build (which will need to be installed separately).

E.g

```
    const myLambdaFunction = new aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, 'myFunction',
    {
    functionName: 'myFunction',
    entry: './lambda/index.ts',
    handler: 'index/handler',
    runtime: aws_lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
    });
```

For details and configuration options see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction.html