# Error: Cannot find module '\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs when invoking Lambda function created with Terraform and Node.js >= 18

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created a Lambda function using Terraform, and my Node.js version is >= 18. I setup the infra based on [article](https://sandny.com/2022/10/06/create-lambda-function-with-terraform/). However, when I try to invoke the Lambda function, I encounter the following error in CloudWatch:

```
     "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'slack-notification'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
```

I'm unsure what is causing this error. Can someone help me understand what could be causing the "Error: Cannot find module 'slack-notification'" when trying to invoke the Lambda function?

**Terraform Infrastructure:**

```
resource "null_resource" "lambda_dependencies" {
  triggers = {
    updated_at = timestamp()
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = <<EOF
      npm install
      EOF
    working_dir = "${path.module}${var.lambda_relative_path}"
  }
}

data "archive_file" "lambda-zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = var.lambda_path
  output_path = "lambda_function.zip"
  depends_on  = [null_resource.lambda_dependencies]
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_module" {
  filename         = data.archive_file.lambda-zip.output_path
  function_name    = "gitlab-slack-integration-${var.environment}"
  role             = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  handler          = "slack-notification.handler"
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda-zip.output_base64sha256
  runtime          = "nodejs18.x"
 
  environment {
    variables = {
      env = var.environment
    }
  }
}
```

**slack-notification.ts file:**

```js
import { SNSEvent, Context } from "aws-lambda";

export const handler = async (event: SNSEvent, context: Context) => {
  const snsMessage = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].Sns.Message);

  console.log({ snsMessage });
  return context.logStreamName;
};
```

Directory structure:

```js
├── src
│   ├── functions
│   │   └── slack-notification.ts
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   └── tsconfig.json
└── terra-infra
    ├── backend-dev.tf
    ├── dev
    │   └── functions
    │       ├── api-gateway.tf
    │       ├── backend.tf
    │       ├── lambda.tf
    │       ├── lambda_function.zip
    │       ├── provider.tf
    │       ├── sns-topic.tf
    │       ├── variables.auto.tfvars
    │       └── variables.tf
    ├── module
    ├── remote-state
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   ├── provider.tf
    │   ├── terraform.tfstate.backup
    │   ├── variables.auto.tfvars
    │   └── variables.tf
    └── run-env.sh
```

Comment: Shouldn't the function be with a `.js` extension and not `.ts`? In other words, shouldn't you create a JS function from the TypeScript one?

Comment: Problem is not `.ts` or `.js`. Something I am setting up wrong and it cause the issue. This person faced the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75678115/error-cannot-find-module-index-nrequire-stack-n-var-runtime-index-mjs, did not get any proper result. 
PS: Also I prefer `.ts`.

Comment: After digging some articles. I think issue is something with `zip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node JS lambda does not support Typescript directly and must be transpiled first with tsc command: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-typescript.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. I might sound stupid but `slack-notification` its a typescript file. how can I install them

Comment: I see, sorry. I dont think the node.js runtime supports using .ts files directly so you must transpile them with tsc first: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-typescript.html

Comment: Hmmm. how does with work with serverless framework then : 
https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/22865199326008b9f863cb1ad28bfdddae9a7473/aws-node-typescript-apollo-lambda/serverless.yml#L21

Comment: That probably transpiles it to javascript as well (when you run serverless deploy). You can still develop in TS but when you need to deploy it you must first “build” it to plain Javascript.

Comment: Like this: https://github.com/juliankrispel/typescript-aws-lambda-terraform/blob/master/webpack.config.js??

Terraform doc is really shit then :D

Comment: You can just run tsc and then zip the build folder and use that 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254301/discussion-between-krisna-and-alex).